Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Freeze when data transfer
I just finished my fresh install of ubuntu 24.04 LTS .
Now i try to copy all my needed data to my new ubuntu .
If i do little by little it's ok BUT , if i do a lot in one time , the system freeze .
I have to restart the computer  and re-try with less .
What can i do ?
Edit 1 :
I am on a hp pavaillion notebook 17 ;
Intel Core i5-5200Ux4 ;
8 gb RAM ;
Intel HD Graphics 5500 ( BDW GT12);
By big amount :  i would says: maybe 40 GB or maybe 10 GB  Copy from my external HDD to the laptop SSD .
I copy the data " graphically" , simply with copy paste  .
I came from ubuntu 23 where all  works nice .

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to AskUbuntu. Could you [edit] your question to include specific information about your hardware? What brand/model of computer are you using? How are you copying data? How much is “a lot”, which results in a system hang? With this information, it may be possible to offer some solutions.

I have exactly the same problem with my fresh Ubuntu 24.04 install. Copying large video files (~5GB) ends up freezing my entire system for about 15 seconds. It also freezes network connections. I have a pretty capable System with SSDs, a recent Ryzen 5, and 64 GB RAM. Same system also has Windows 10 as dual boot. No such problems copying the exact same files around. I believe it has to be a problem with the file system configuration. My guess is ext4 or maybe LVM with encryption enabled. I believe the freeze happens due to intense computation in the background when copying files. (IMHO)

do your copy commands from a terminal not some "graphical" drag and drop app

At first it seems unrelated but considering the two answers that far, might this be related to a previous, unanswered question?  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1517496/large-usb-transfer-rate-significantly-slower-on-ubuntu-24-04

I am also facing the exact same problem in fresh installation of Kubuntu 24.04. First, I thought that it's a problem with Dolphin as it was reported already at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dolphin/+bug/2069648. However, even while copying with cp (with -fR flags) from terminal, the entire system freezes. I have around 39000 files to copy (around 40 GB data). It has failed repeatedly. It's for sure is a bug related to some other part (filesystem or something), not just Dolphin file manager alone.
EDIT (MY ISSUE IS SOLVED):
My problem is resolved after deleting all the __pycache__ directories recursively in my Code folder. I got a hint for it from Comment-4 of https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/816198. First, I tested by copying all the other normal folders (like Documents, Downloads, Videos etc) except my 'Code' folder (in which I've multiple programs in Rust, Python etc etc) one by one and confirmed that the copying is happening fine. Then I tried to copy my 'Code' folder which has around hundred or so __pycache__ directories in various sub-folders. Then the system has frozen as it did earlier. Then, I have deleted all the __pycache__ folders recursively with find . -type d -name "__pycache__" -exec rm -rf {} + and then retried copying my 'Code' directory and this time it has worked. Strange. Anyhow, I am posting this here because others may try some other ways based on these hints just as I did from the above link.
Note: To be clear, this is copying data from removable disk to my laptop, not the other way around.

If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the Ask Question button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - From Review

As per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869024/what-is-pycache , When you run a program in Python, the interpreter compiles it to bytecode first and stores it in the pycache folder.
